# CodeIgniter - AJAX,STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, procedure

I don't know how to begin this but here's the statement before the problem.

THE URL -> **my.com/kustomer/customerListOfApplication/24669**

I got a modal that accepts more than 10 fields.

I got the PROCEDURE call in a model.

```
  public function insertApplicationAjax(){

    $inType           = $this->input->post('lineType');
    $inCustomer       = $this->input->post('custId');
    //echo $inType;die();
    $inMeter          = $this->input->post('meter');
    $inIfBusiness     = strtoupper($this->input->post('business'));
    $inDeposit        = $this->input->post('deposit');
    $inApplicationFee = $this->input->post('applicationFee');
    $inServiceFee     = $this->input->post('serviceFee');
    $inOtherFee       = $this->input->post('otherFee');
    $inInitialReading = $this->input->post('initialReading');
    $inDateApplied    = date('Y-m-d');
    $inNote           = strtoupper($this->input->post('note'));
    $inLocation       = strtoupper($this->input->post('add1'));
    $inCluster        = $this->input->post('cluster');
    $inZone           = $this->input->post('zone');
    $inTypeOfService  = 1; //application 2 Reconnection 3 Promisory
    $inCustomerName   = strtoupper($this->input->post('customerName'));
    $indiscountBit   = $this->input->post('discountBit');
    // echo $indiscountBit;die();
    $inBrgyCode       = $this->input->post('brgy');
    $inPipe       = $this->input->post('pipe');


    $sql = "CALL APPLICATION_ADD(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($inType,$inCustomer,$inMeter,$inIfBusiness,$inDeposit,$inApplicationFee,$inServiceFee,$inOtherFee,$inInitialReading,$inDateApplied,$inNote,$inLocation,$inCluster,$inZone,$inTypeOfService,$inCustomerName,$indiscountBit,$inBrgyCode,$inPipe));
    if (!$query) {
      return  $this->db->error();
    }else {
      return true;
      mysqli_next_result( $this->db->conn_id );
    }
  }
```

Here's the AJAX

```js
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(b, a, c) {
  return this.optional(a) || b != c
 }, "Please input a value other than this...");

 var validator = $( "#newAccountForm" ).validate({
  submitHandler: function(d) {
   var url = "http://my.com/application/insertApplicationAjax";//$('#newAccountForm').attr('action');
   var msg;
   if (url == "http://my.com/application/insertApplicationAjax") {
    $('#submitApplicationBtn').prop('disabled', true).text('Please wait...');
    msg = "New Application Successfully Added...";
   }else {
    $('#submitApplicationBtn').prop('disabled', true).text('Updating...');
    msg = "Application Edited Successfully... &#128521;";
   }
   var formData = $('#newAccountForm').serialize(); //alert(formData);
   $.post(url, formData, function(data,s) {
    if (s = "success") {
     if (data.data == true) {
      toastr.success(msg);
      setTimeout(function(){
       $("#customerForm")[0].reset();
       $('#addCustomerModal').modal('hide');
       $('#submitApplicationBtn').removeAttr('disabled').text('SUBMIT');
      }, 800);
      // $('#customerTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();// refreshTable();
      customerTable.ajax.reload();
     } else {
      $('#submitApplicationBtn').removeAttr('disabled').text('TRY AGAIN..');
      alert('You didn\'t changed something.');
     }
    }else {
     $('#submitApplicationBtn').removeAttr('disabled').text('TRY AGAIN..');
     alert('Something went wrong try again.');
    }
   }, "json");
  },
   invalidHandler: function() {
   toastr.warning(validator.numberOfInvalids() +' field(s) are invalid');
   },
  rules: {
   meter: {
    required: true,
    notEqual: 0,
    normalizer: function( value ) {
    return $.trim( value );
    }
   },
   brgy:{
    notEqual: 0,
   },
   initialReading: {
    required: false,
   },
   zone: {
    required: true,
    // rangelength: [2, 30]
   },
   cluster: {
    required: true,
    // rangelength: [2, 30]
   },
   add1: {
    required: true
   },
  },
  messages: {
   brgy: {
    required: "***",
   },
   zone: {
   required: "***",
  },
  cluster: {
   required: "***",
  },
  add1: {
   required: "***",
  },
  meter: {
   required: "***",
  },
  }
 });
```

Here's the Observation and PROBLEM

it seems that i cannot pass the serialized data from the form to the model, but i can see the data on chrome inspect element.

[image]

Thrown error:

[image]

I did try to to use the PROCEDURE on phpmyadmin and it was fine.

Comment: Did you check post value ?

Comment: Is it the Form Values form the form? Yes, I did - serialize data.